# VS Code cannot read Node Modules file when doing yarn install (it can read when doing npm install)

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, yarnpkg

When ever I install my packages using `Yarn`, VS Code is not able to read the node_module files that are using in index.js or for that matter anywhere.  However, when I do `npm install`, it starts working fine.

How can I fix this?

System: Mac - tried different Macs, same result.

Comment: did you try `yarn add` ?

Comment: Yes. I tried that too. But does not help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and I had to do `yarn init` to get the `package.json` file to appear in the folder. Once I did that, adding a `yarn add` added the node_modules in the folder in vscode.